# Rsync not creating subfolders automatically within same origin and destination paths on different servers

Tags: filesystem, directory, nginx, webserver, rsync

I am running this rsync via cron hourly to sync my websites automatically to the secondary servers from the primary.

`rsync -avz --del -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/user-key -pXXXXX -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /var/www/ USERNAME@IPV4:/var/www/`, where XXXXX is a valid port number on the destination server, USERNAME is a valid username with the key file given (present and equal on the primary and all secondary servers), and IPV4 is a valid IPv4 address.

I have another identical command, just with `/var/www/` replaced with `/etc/nginx/` to sync all nginx configuration files, and that one works as intended. It syncs all subdirectories including their symbolic links. The only difference is in the folder structure and not in the command. The `/etc/nginx/` directory contains all of the necessary folders upon nginx's installation, whereas `/var/www/` has a subdirectory `html/` on all servers (this is part of nginx's installation), but a subdirectory `SUBDIR/` that I created on the primary server is not synced via rsync to the destination secondary servers.

In effect, this command needs to be modified somehow so that rsync creates any necessary subdirectories that are new and syncs their entire contents. At the moment, this has broken my website for the time being, at the cost of being more futureproofed for any additional websites I'd like to host on the servers in the future.

Your help is appreciated.

Rsync Noob

Comment: I suspect that the problem is permissions: The way you run `rsync` does not have the permissions to create a subfolder in `/var/www/`

Comment: You should include the output of the failed command in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was permissions. I had not run the additional command to change ownership and group of /var/www even though permissions were coming up correct in my FTP client.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) Please make sure that the modified permissions do not open a security hole in your server.